# Loading a map only once in application life cycle by reading a file in c++

Tags: c++, tld

i want to load a map by reading a file in a application startup, and want to utilize this map in some other class  to look up for a particular string and execute logic.

Loading of a map should be done only once in application life cycle.

would like to know best approach to declare this map and access in some other logic.

Comment: _"would like to know best approach to declare this map and access in some other logic."_ Pass a `std::map<>` instance (`const` reference) around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach would be to load it once

```
const std::map<key_type,value_type>& theMap = loadMap();
```

and pass the `const` reference to other functions:

```
 std::map<key_type,value_type>::const_iterator 
 find_key(key_type key, const std::map<key_type,value_type>& map) {
     return map.find(key);
 }
```

Comment: Probably, since you need somewhere to store the map. A class with an appropriate member variable is probably a better solution that a global variable or a static local variable in the `loadMap()` function.